# php - object data catch error missing attributes

Tags: php

I read some data from an API, than I tired to use it,  but sometime parts of the data is missing, i.e.

```
$api_response->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimension
```

if any of the attributes are missing it will generate a php error, I'm looking for a way to catch this error as an exception.

I can write the following code:

```
if (!property_exists($this->api_response->Items,"Item") ) 
    throw new Exception("Can't use AM API", 1);

if (!property_exists($this->api_response->Items->Item,"ItemAttributes") ) 
    throw new Exception("Can't use AM API", 1);
```

but it's tedious and ugly, is there a shorter/cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some kind of proxy to simplify this

```
<?php

class PropertyProxy{
    private $value;
    public function __construct($value){
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name){
        if(!property_exists($this->value, $name)){
            throw new Exception("Property: $name is not available");
        }
        return new self($this->value->{$name});
    }
    public function getValue(){
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$proxiedResponse = new PropertyProxy($api_response);

$proxiedResponse->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimension->getValue();
```

Comment: Can I do the same idea with sub-classing?

Comment: I mean 'Object Inheritance', i.e. inherit from an object that throw exception if an attribute is missing